# New Class Instance or Everything in One - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have an `AdminController`which loads all the views, although I will need to pass in information into that view.

Example Users Tab - View total users, new users, viewing the users profile etc, editing them.

Is it better to create a new controller to do those methods in and then in the `AdminController` to call `$users = new UsersController;` ?

I am trying to find the most efficient way OOP.

Comment: There is definitely no reason to call `new Controller;` in another controller. Other then that it's really up to you how you want to separate controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a UsersController. It sounds like a [resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers) would be your best option.

Do `php artisan make:controller UsersController --resource` and then add this to your routes file:

```
Route::resource('admin/users', 'UsersController')->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Yes I have actually done that before you answered but thank you!